# Django model field for file system directory path

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

In the Django model field types reference I could not find a field for a file system directory path. With [custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-model-fields/) it's possible to implement this. What should be considered w.r.t. validation? Can I extend Django's builtin model field types with a package?

Comment: What wrong with [FilePathField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield) ?

Comment: To me it's not clear how to restrict FilePathField to directory paths (validation should assert file paths).

Comment: According to the doc, `allow_files=False, allow_folders=True` should restrict to directory path only. If this doesn't answer your question, please edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers In case validation is handled by `FilePathFIeld(allow_files=False, allow_folders=True)` I'd accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: Same problem here. Tried with FilePathField, but I'm having an error claiming the empty value is not a valid path, when I try to create an instance with django admin

Comment: How do we make it accept any filepath in the filesystem?